# ExtJs with GateIn not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, gatein

I added ExtJS (I am using ExtJs 3.2) libraries on gatein-resources.xml (I am using GateIn 3.6) with following way

```
<module>
            <name>ext-base</name>
            <script>
                <path>/javascript/lib/ext-2.1/adapter/ext/ext-base.js</path>
            </script>

    </module>
<module>
            <name>ext-all</name>
            <script><path>/javascript/lib/ext-2.1/ext-all.js</path></script>
            <depends>
                <module>ext-base</module>
            </depends>
    </module>
    <module>
            <name>extCommons</name>
            <script><path>/javascript/commons/extCommons.js</path></script>
            <depends>
                <module>ext-base</module>
            </depends>
    </module>
.....
    <portal>
        <name>MyPortal</name>
        <module>
            <depends>
                <module>ext-base</module>
            </depends>
            <depends>
                <module>extCommons</module>
            </depends>
            <depends>
                <module>ext-all</module>
            </depends>
        </portal>
```

But  i got **Ext not defined** error on my firebug console when i start GateIn

Also [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/071ntw7oln4j1ld/ext-base-in-gatein-resource.js) i am attaching the ext-base.js file processed by gatein-resources.xml file ([Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tfj5w60jq6o28x7/ext-base.js) is the original ext-base.js)

But it is working fine on GateIn 3.2. On that version i used <javascript> tag for adding javascript gatein-resources.xml file. But this tag is not recommended in GateIn 3.6 so i am using the above specified tags on gatein-resources.xml

**How to Reproduce This issue: -** [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/071ntw7oln4j1ld/ext-base-in-gatein-resource.js) is the ext-base.js file which comes header tag of gateIn while starting GateIn and this ext-base.js file added via gatein-resources.xml. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tfj5w60jq6o28x7/ext-base.js) is the original ext-base.js. The difference of  both of these files are on ext-base.js from gatein which contains some additional lines of codes which is follows

```
define('SHARED/ext-base', [], function() {
var require = eXo.require, requirejs = eXo.require,define = eXo.define;
eXo.define.names=[];
eXo.define.deps=[];
return //Continued by original ext-base code
});
```

But if you run this code on firebug console and execute 'Ext' command the firebug return an error which is **"Ext not defined"**.
[image]
 But if you run the original code then you can successfully execute the 'Ext' command successfully. 
[image]
I repeat 'i am using GateIn as development mode'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly import the javascripts between `<portal>...</portal>` tags using `<script>` tag. For that you need to arrange gatein-resource.xml like following

```
    <portal>
        <name>MyPortal</name>
            <scripts>
                    <script><path>/javascript/lib/DwrProxy.js</path></script>
                    <script><path>/javascript/commons/validation.js</path></script>
                    <script><path>/javascript/lib/ext-2.1/ext-all-debug.js</path></script>
                    ...
            </scripts>
    </portal>
```